# Unable to get the required output using a LIST, <cfloop> and <cfquery>

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a LIST (query output)that has the distinct ID’s from a table “Account”.
Using that LIST  I am LOOPING over a SELECT query and basically extracting some  COUNT  .
I am having trouble getting the COUNT value on an individual basis.

The table “Account” has the fields 
1) contract_ID ,
2)vAccountID(primary key) and 
3) Status_id (values=’’,V,C).

I am doing the following query

```
    <cfquery name="qryGetid" datasource="#datasource#">
 SELECT DISTINCT(contract_ID )  
 FROM Account
    ORDER BY contract_ID DESC
</cfquery>


<!---   account details for each --->
<cfset  Z =#ValueList(qryGetid.ID)# >
<cfloop list="#Z#" index="Y"   >  
<cfquery name="qryGetNiceAccounts"  datasource="#dataSource#">
 SELECT 
 DISTINCT(a.contract_ID )
 ,(SELECT count(vAccountID) FROM Account
        WHERE c _ID IN (<cfqueryparam value="#x#" list="yes" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" separator=",">)
        AND Status_id = 'V' )   AS Valid_AcntV
 ,(SELECT count(vAccountID) FROM Account
        WHERE c _ID IN (<cfqueryparam value="#x#" list="yes" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" separator=",">)
        AND Status_id = 'C' )   AS Valid_AcntC 

  FROM  Account a
  WHERE   
 a.contract_ID  IN (<cfqueryparam value="#x#" list="yes" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" separator="," >)
 ORDER BY   contract_ID   DESC

</cfquery>
```

The query ="qryGetNiceAccounts"   is returning only one value for “Valid_AcntCount”  even for different “c_ID” in the list .

Example if the “Account” table has the values

```
contract_ID      count(vID)/ v_Accoun t=’v’     count(vID)/ v_Accoun t=’c’

    123           10                                                  220
    124           05                                                  110
    123           01                                                     0

 contract_ID   count(vID)/ v_Accoun t=’v’     count(vID)/ v_Accoun t=’c’
    123           10                                                  220
    124           10                                                  220
    123           10                                                  220
```

Basically I am having trouble getting COUNTS  for individual IDs.

Side note:-When I do a dump the Input “contract_ID ” is showing as 123, 123 123 rather than 123,124,125

Comment: if you do a <cfdump var="#qryGetid#">, what do you see?

Comment: Side note: Why do you loop over a `ValueList()` from a query when you could just loop over the query itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> […] Using that LIST I am LOOPING over a SELECT query and basically extracting some COUNT. […]

This is generally a bad idea. Especially "getting some counts" is one of the easiest things to do directly in SQL and more often than not there is no reason to execute a SELECT query in a loop. Avoid that whenever you can for performance reasons.

And in your case it's perfectly avoidable (it even makes your code a lot simpler), just change your SQL:

```
<cfquery name="qryGetNiceAccounts"  datasource="#dataSource#">
  SELECT
    contract_ID,
    (SELECT COUNT(vAccountID) FROM v_Account 
      WHERE c_ID = a.contract_ID AND Status_id = 'V'
    ) AS Valid_AcntV,
    (SELECT COUNT(vAccountID) FROM v_Account 
      WHERE c_ID = a.contract_ID AND Status_id = 'C'
    ) AS Valid_AcntC
  FROM
    (SELECT contract_ID FROM Account GROUP BY contract_ID) AS a
  ORDER BY
    contract_ID DESC
</cfquery>
```

You don't need the other query at all, neither do you need the loop.

An alternative way to express the same would be this:

```
SELECT
  a.contract_ID,
  SUM(CASE Status_id WHEN 'V' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Valid_AcntV,
  SUM(CASE Status_id WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Valid_AcntC
FROM
  Account AS a
  INNER JOIN v_Account AS c ON c.c_id = a.contract_ID
GROUP BY 
  a.contract_ID
ORDER BY
  a.contract_ID DESC
```

This would hit the `v_Account` view only once. You must determine for yourself what is the most efficient query.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're overcomplicating it, and it can be solved with a single query with a few joins:

```
SELECT 
    a.contract_ID, 
    COUNT(vav.vAccountID) AS Valid_AcntV, 
    COUNT(vac.vAccountID) AS Valid_AcntC
FROM  Account a
LEFT JOIN v_Account AS vav 
    ON vav.c_ID = a.contract_ID AND vav.Status_id = 'V'
LEFT JOIN v_Account AS vac 
    ON vac.c_ID = a.contract_ID AND vac.Status_id = 'C'
GROUP BY   a.contract_ID
ORDER BY   a.contract_ID   DESC
```

Should do what you're after, if I'm deciphering your queries correctly.

Comment: +1 That's the alternative to my group first/select counts later approach.

Comment: Thanks! but i would like to mention I changed the table "v_Account" IN ... "LEFT JOIN v_Account AS vav.." to "Account".

Comment: Basically inner join onto itself This slows the query a lot.

Comment: Should I use a SELF JOIN here.aLSO i need to find a couple of more COUNTS from the same table.

Comment: @Fransis: Have you tried my approach as well? It could well be that it is faster than this one.

Comment: yup i did try urs,Tomalak and it was faster,but as i said i need to find a couple of more COUNTS(from the same table ) and do some more JOINS (from another table). So was getting error while doing all these joins. will update soon.Thanks a lot

Comment: @Fransis, ah yes, was me reading your queries wrong.  is c_ID indexed? how many Status_Ids are there too? it's probably worth creating an index on the accounts table for "c_id, status_id", also since it's the same table the group by and order needs the table alias too.. will update my answer.

Comment: the COUNT(vAccountID) /Pkey for the whole table is ~ 9000 results

Comment: index c_id at least, you'll find mine and Tomalak's query will run much faster.